# based on a <tr> information click on a hyperlink in the same <tr><td> using Python

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi I am trying to click on a hyperlink that lies inside a `<table>` and inside a particular `<tr><td>` below is what the HTML looks like

```
<tr><td>Clinic</td><td style="text-align:center">MN</td><td style="text-align:center">&nbsp;</td><td style="text-align:center"><input type="hidden" name="3572" value="1"><input type="checkbox" name="Alert_3572" value="1" checked="true"></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;text-align:center;"><a href="muniInfo.jsp?OBLI=3572&amp;current=FILING_HISTORY">Filing History</a></td><td style="text-align:center"></td></tr>

<tr><td>My Clinic</td><td style="text-align:center">MN</td><td style="text-align:center">&nbsp;</td><td style="text-align:center"><input type="hidden" name="3540" value="1"><input type="checkbox" name="Alert_3540" value="1" checked="true"></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;text-align:center;"><a href="muniInfo.jsp?OBLI=3540&amp;current=FILING_HISTORY">Filing History</a></td><td style="text-align:center"></td></tr>
```

what I need to do here is click on the `<a href>` tag for the value Clinic however the value for the name (name="3572") is not know so based on the value of the `<td>` = "Clinic" I need to click on the relevant hyperlink using python

I was able to retrieve all the tr and td tags using beautiful soup but don't know how to match the value clinic and then click on the adjoining hyperlink.

any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a xpath query to retrieve the element.

It is like the following

```
"//tr[td[text()='Clinic']]/td/a"
```

This will bring to you the `a` tag of a `tr` that contains a `td` with his text equals `Clinic`